# Ethernet port re-transmission frequently

Tags: networking, ethernet, tcp

We have a laptop that uses its Ethernet port to connect to a device-local network, and wireless for Internet.

Recently we installed Wireshark to diagnose some network problem. We found a lot of TCP re-transmission packets (which indicated as dark or red or other unconformable colors).

Our observation is that this only happened in the Ethernet port. Even it is connected to the Internet it is still the same situation. However the same thing does not happen in the wireless link.

Also, the re-transmission happened very frequently and usually repeated 4 times. For example, we observed 4 continuously duplicated SYN before any other packets (interval less than 200ms). This is unusual, since I think TCP re-transmission shall only happen when time-out occurs.

It looks like the source is in the laptop end, because 1) the above SYN packets were sent from the laptop; 2) when connecting to Internet, connections to all over the world have the same problem.

There is no noticeable effects in the application level. But I wonder what is wrong with this Ether port? What shall we do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a similar issue before, where I would see duplicate TCP packets being sent, about 3 per packet if I recall.

The issue I had was with drivers/software installed in Windows.

To rule out the possibility of it being a hardware issue, boot up in a linux LiveCD and verify whether the issue occurs then. If not, it's likely a driver/application issue in Windows (I'm assuming Windows here, correct me if I'm wrong).

How I found mine, was by going to Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings.

From there, right click on the adapter and click Properties.

You should see a window like this:

[image]

The problem I had, was that there was a piece of software installed (particularly, a wireless hotspot application) that was causing the repeated TCP packets.

My recommendation is to look under your network adapter, and try to find items that do not look like they came with Windows, temporarily disable them (one at a time), and perform the tests with Wireshark again to see if the problem has gone away.

Comment: Thanks for this greate answer. There is a "load balance" filter in the list, and if I disable this it is fine.